# Java Cucumber Step Definition for vertical DataTable

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-jvm

I'm using [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm). I have the following in a .feature file:

```
  Background:
    Given the following account file line:
      | First Name     | Lance  |
      | Last Name      | Fisher |
      | Corporate Name |        |
```

This is a vertically-oriented table. The following generated step definition uses First Name and Lance as the headers, where First Name, Last Name, and Corporate Name should be the headers.

```
@Given("^the following account file line:$")
public void the_following_account_file_line(DataTable arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    // For automatic conversion, change DataTable to List<YourType>
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

How would I implement a step definition to handle a vertical table rather than a horizontal table?

Comment: What's the reason for going vertical? The very benefit of a table is that it allows for multiple test cases to be handled succinctly in a table format. Going vertical eliminates that benefit by limiting the number of test cases handled.

Comment: I have more headers than records so it would be nice to fit them on my screen without having to scroll to the right.

Answer (score 4):

Just receive the value on parameter as `Map<String, String>` instead of DataTable. Cucumber will convert the first columns as map keys and the second column as map values.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple enough, as the Datatable can return an array of arrays of strings, and you can step through this in whatever manner you wish.

However, I'd agree with Prakash Murthy that the horizontal table is more usual and useable.